# How to do exponential regression, but not the straightforward way (logarithm+linear regression)?

Tags: regression, least-squares

I have data points: $x_k[i]$, $k=1..10$, $i=0..10000$, each $x_k$ is data from a damped oscillation (starts around 1, and has exponential-like decaying. The higher the $k$, the faster the decay).

And I have an exponential function: $e^{-({b_1+b_2k^2})i}$

I'd like to find $b_1$ and $b_2$ which makes the exponential fit to my data points.

Taking the logarithm and using linear regression (least squares) is bad for this problem, because it exaggerates differences for small values, so I get a bad fit at small $i$ values.

Currently, I use a brute-force method (try a lot of $b_1\times b_2$ pairs), which works well (I can use least squares error condition in the original problem space, not in log space), but it is an ugly and inefficient solution.

Is there a better method to solve this?

Comment: how did you obtain those data points? was it generated by an algorithm?

Comment: @pranavB23: no, data is from a physical process

Comment: brute force seems good. Try to graph it and try fitting a known curve and approximate

Comment: You can use least squares but weight the errors more heavily for large i

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to use the linearization that you have mentioned and perform OLS and use the OLS estimators of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ as a starting point in non-linear regression for the Newton-Raphson algorithm. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm

Hopefully, the OLS coefficients will be close enough to the global minimum, and then the algorithm wouldn't need more than few iteration to converge. Any statistical software can easily perform the task.

Comment: Does OLS stand for "ordinary least squares"? I haven't seen that abbreviation before.

Comment: Your'e right https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares